# Chrome 65 download security bug/error

Tags: google-chrome, security, download

[image: Error screen]

I wanted to download a signature file from a trusted source.
It is normal that this little warning pops up, but normally there is a button to accept the download. 
But since i use Chrome 65 there is only reject ("Verwerfen").

The Download is stoped and makes no further progress so simple waiting is not enough.

Has somebody ever experienced this behavior?

And a related question:
Where would you report this problem?
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new ?

[Update] The possibility to accept the download is available in the downloads page of chrome.

Comment: Discussed in Google Chrome Help Forum: When downloading, 'Keep' button is hidden, showing only 'Discard' button https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/0jZPqSVuGcM